# Pandas read json file: "Expected object or value"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json

orderbook_file = "/home/viktor/code/Keyrock/orderbook.json"
orderbook = pd.read_json("orderbook_file")
```

When I run this in the terminal it does not find my json file and thus can not read it... what am I doing wrong? Sorry for the silly question, rather new to pandas... Thanks!!

Comment: When I run the command json.loads("orderbook_file.json") it shows me the following error: No json object could be detected! At least the error message changed... is it still related to my json file format? Thanks!

Comment: Thats the code I tried: json.loads("orderbook_file.json")

Comment: @viktor.w: your code sample suggests that you have mixed up a filename (`"orderbook_file"`) and a *variable* that's containing a filename (`orderbook_file`). Just removing the doublequotes from the last line in your example should make it run, if there is a JSON file located at `/home/viktor/code/Keyrock/orderbook.json`.

Comment: I tried and it still does not work... when I do: json_data=open("orderbook_file.json").read(), it reads it! But when I want to apply pandas.read_json(my_json_file) I still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick check and it looks like you are importing the orderbook part wrong, this works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json

orderbook_file = "file:///Users/test-user/scripts/test.json"
orderbook = pd.read_json(orderbook_file)
print(orderbook)
```

This works without error, If you look at the official documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html it's expecting a file pointer URL to find the json file.

Also you created the orderbook_file object but didn't use it inside the pd.read_json, so even if the file was pointing correctly it wouldn't have found it.

Comment: No I am sorry but it still does not work, I have the same message error...

Comment: It would seem like your json is malformed then I used the Json sample data from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON and it worked fine, please try that first then validate your json is not malformed by using something like jq or https://jsonlint.com/